# How can I add an arbritrary label to a detail in a Plot or Plot3D?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, labeling

I know about the graphics primitives Line and Point.

I also know about Labeled, but there the placement of the label itself is confined to one out of {Bottom, Left, Top, Right}.

**I am looking for a Graphics and for a Graphics3D primitive which displays some Text at a defined position with respect to coordinates in the Graphics or Graphics3D. Of course, if it is in a 3D Graphics and if I turn the Graphics3D around, I would like the lable move around like the numbers and labels attached to axes do and the connecting lines od curves move with it.**

I guess there is already such a graphics primitive which is e.g. used to draw the numbers associated to axes' scales, axes' labels etc. However I don't know its name and I don't know how it can be used.

If I had such a primitive, I would use this to add a connecting line from the the text placed in or around the Graphics or Graphics3D to the specific detail in order do draw the attention that specific detail to be labelled. I want to make drawings like those in dictionaries, where you see reference numbers or text labels connected to details in the drawing (in patents, the connection lines are often curved ones between the label and the detail and they might  they might be done by Bezier splines).

Comment: What about `Graphics3D[Text["this is my text", {x0, y0, z0} ] ]`?

Comment: A more concrete example would be `Show[
 ListPointPlot3D@RandomReal[10, {10, 3}],
 Graphics3D[Text["text", {3, 3, 3}]]
 ]`